# В textarea появляется пустой текст вместо placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Добры день.
В textarea появляется пустой текст.

```
<textarea class="text-required" id="text-comment" placeholder="Текст комментария"
data-item_type="comment" name="comment[body]" 
style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; height: 89px;">
</textarea>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так это выглядит в js туда ничего не добавляется.
С чем это может быть связано? Буду благодарен за любые идеи.

Comment: Код, который вы привели тут, отлично выводит текст placeholder. Может быть, дело в других частях кода вашего проекта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите контент из textarea (пробелы и переносы строк).

Вот это:

```
<textarea>


</textarea>
```

выдаст вам пустой текст. А чтобы плейсхолдер отображался, текста там быть не должно.

вот так правильно:

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.